# `Get List of all PLC Data block by MOKA

Tags: java, plc

I try `snap7` project and i find very useful functions. but in java version of `snap7` (`moka library`) some methods is missing.

for example, now, I want to get list of all data block (DB). in `c`, there is a method (`Cli_ListBlocksOfTyp`) but I don't know how to do it in `moka`.

anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1):

The reason is, that not all functions are ported in moka. As you can see in the  [MOKA overview](http://snap7.sourceforge.net/moka7.html#overview).
The overview also contains all functions providet by MOKA.

Hope it was helpfull.